# Searching for alternative solution for Contact Picker for taskser

Tags: contacts, tasker

I am using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) scences. I have a text-box. I want the user to enter contact phone number into the input-box in the scene.

I am searching how to let the user pick a number from the contact list.

Tasker don't have any plugin that show contact picker.

Do you have any other solution for that?

Comment: Just saying: You can try your luck [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/) too. If you do find an answer, don't forget to share it with us. :)

Comment: If you need answeryou need to do +1 and star. It give the asker motivation for sharing answer. Thanks

Comment: I know about that but your question doesn't show efforts (at least not something I could see, that's subjective, please don't bomb me) and if  I need an answer then I would consider offering a bounty rather than simply marking it as favorite.

Comment: For Readers: Here is a pointer which uses [AutoContact](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autocontacts) app: https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/3lwjff/help_how_to_searching_for_alternative_solution/

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate).
Automate  is like Tasker but it also has  Contact Picker.

I can start automate flow from Tasker, then the flow can pick a contact and copy the contact number to clipboard. Then Tasker can take the number from the clipboard and do whatever I want.

Hard, but it is working!!!

On the way, I found that Automate is much better than Tasker (Automate can run Tasker's tasks and plugins either)